# entropy minimization for inhomogeneity correction in python

Tags: python, entropy

Does somebody know about a entropy minimization implementation in python?
I want to use this to correct inhomogeneity in histology images.

[Reference](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1046/j.1365-2818.2002.01079.x/full) about the algorithm I am talking about.

Comment: I couldn't find a open implementation of it but here is a online-software by the author to test it:
http://lit.fe.uni-lj.si/contents/tools/InhomogeneityCorrection/

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you'll have to hack something together yourself, maybe using [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) and [pyentropy](http://code.google.com/p/pyentropy/).